# How to run excel vba code from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, excel, windows-services, vba

I want to run some excel vba code from my Windows Service. The Service is using a fileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory for an xml file to be added. Once a file is added the content of the xml file is deserialized into object properties. At this stage I want to open an excel file and pass these values in to certain cells and run vba code from that work book. I have this working perfectly from a windows forms application but I cant get it working from my Windows Service application. I attached a debugger to the application to try and see what was happening but there were no errors thrown and all the steps completed successfully. I know a Windows Service does not support opening MS Office files as there is issues with interacting with the UI and the User permissions it has. But I am looking for a work around any way to be able to get this vba code running from a service. I am using Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit and I have my Account for my service set to LocalSystem.This is the code that I am using:

```
    private void FSWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
            Trade t;
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            XmlReader reader;
            XmlWriter writer;

            string filePath = @"C:\Inbox\TradeInfo.xml";


            serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Trade));
            reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath);
            t = (Trade)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();



            string path=@"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop\TwsDde.xls";

            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            oXL.Visible = true;

            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

            mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path,2, false, 5, "", "", true,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true,false, false);

            //Get all the sheets in the workbook

            mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;

            //Get the allready exists sheet

            mWSheet1=(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Basic Orders");

            // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range= mWSheet1.UsedRange;

            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 1] = "GE";
            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 2] = "STK";
            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 7] = "SMART";
            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 9] = "USD";
            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 12] = "Buy";
            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 13] = "100";
            mWSheet1.Cells[12, 14] = "MKT";

            Excel.Range range;
            Excel.Range row;

            range = mWSheet1.get_Range("A12", "O12");
            range.EntireRow.Select();

            oXL.Run("TwsDde.xls!Sheet2.placeOrder");
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or alternative ways of doing the same thing i.e running a windows form that contains this code maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I managed to get this working in a kind of round about way. I basically followed this tutorial and code on [launch an interactive process from a service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite) to allow the service to run as SYSTEM user but to adopt the session ID for the first logged on user and give the user Administrative privileges to run interactive processes such as GUI applications. To open excel and run a macro through a Windows service I first wrote all the code to do this in a Windows Forms application and tested it worked there first. I then changed the executable and it worked perfectly. I hope this helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: FWIW, this does not answer the question that was asked. You asked "I want to run an excel macro from my Windows Service" and are proposing as the answer, running the excel macro outside the Windows Service.

Answer (score 5):

What you are attempting to do is [not supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

You can automate Excel if the process is run in an interactive desktop. Attempts to automate Excel from a non-interactive desktop (e.g. from a session) are not supported and fail.

Comment: Ok what about if I called a Windows form that I already wrote which calls the macro automatically without any user interaction? Or would this problem still exist as in excel would still realise it is being called by a SYSTEM account and not a user account?

Comment: You need the process to be running on an interactive desktop. And that rules out a service. If it's a desktop app running on the logged in user's desktop then you are fine.

Comment: Ok. Basically what I am trying to do is read values from an xml file when it is added to a directory being watched by a file system watcher and then store these values and pass them on to a trading API that I am using for Interactive Brokers. Currently I am using the excel API but there is other API's available these are: C++,Active X, Java and POSIX. I am really new to programming and Windows Services which API would work best with my C# Windows Service do you think?

Comment: I've absolutely no idea. I don't know what these other APIs are. I just answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Alright ok just thought I would try and pick your brain some more. Thanks again for the reply is much appreciated.

Comment: @SparcU Are you asking me?

Comment: No user1948787. I have exact same problem. I can start Excel with CreateProcessAsUser but COM automation does not work from Windows Service.

Comment: You cannot automate Excel from a service. See my answer. You need your process to run on an interactive desktop.

Comment: But user1948787 just wrote that he was able to do just that!

Comment: @SparcU No. His so called answer describes running a process on the interactive desktop and getting that to automate Excel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26895/discussion-between-sparcu-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 0):

The Excel is working nice under user service without "desktop interacting" enabled.
**First**, The standard ways to creating Excel COM not working under service. You need launch Excel.exe process from you program - use ShellExecuteEx(recomended way) or CreateProcess(not recomended) to do it.
 
**Second** stage: Attach to Excel COM Application object using GetActiveObject. Now you can correctly access to all Excel COM interfaces.
Also in several operating systems the Excel may be work incorrectly crash under LocalSystem Account - to correct this manually create 2 folders:
        C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\desktop
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\config\systemprofile\desktop
Other bug under service without desctop interacting the Excel in first time ask the user credentials and freeze in memory. You can disable it in registry or interface (see Excel help). Other information about launching processes is [there](http://strongcpp.blogspot.ru/2013/04/blog-post_8.html).