# Running Excel macro from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, excel, windows-services

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054332/how-to-run-an-excel-macro-from-a-windows-service). Note that the accepted answer does not answer the question posed, so I'm creating a new question.

I have a windows service that will open an Excel document, which has a macro that should run automatically when it is opened. I do this by creating a new `Process`. When I run my service, I have it log on as another account to do this (through `Properties -> Log On -> Log on as [some other account]` in the services manager).

The problem is that the macro does not run. When I check the active processes via Task Manager, I see that `EXCEL.EXE` is there, running under the `other account` name.

So I believe the service is properly opening the document in Excel, but the macro is not running. However in the other thread, people seemed to say that it was not possible to open MS Office documents through a service? I am trying to understand what's going on when my service attempts to open the document, and how I can get the macro to run. Any input or clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that Excel doesn't run macros unless the workbook is visible/activated? Another explanation could be macro security kicking in for the Excel sheet because of the way you've opened it, have you tried opening it in user interactive mode (non-hidden) to see if the macro runs then?

Comment: I have Excel set to enable all macros, but you could be right. Could you explain how to open it in user interactive mode? I'm new to this, so I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Maybe this is part of the issue - if you aren't passing any special command line parameters to hide Excel, then possibly it needs the user to execute it from the windows UI for it to open in the right way. Are you passing any command line arguments to Excel (I assume you are passing the workbook name?). I don't really know that much about how windows works beneath the surface though

Comment: I pass Excel the path to the workbook. I am able to open it and run the macro if I run my c# code as an .exe rather than installing as a service, so I that works.

Comment: Must be that then, since services don't run in the same way as regular applications I'd imagine that your Excel is not sitting in the place it expects to sit and therefore macros are affected - is there any other workaround you can employ? Do the processes need to be macros?

Comment: Note that question you've linked provides Microsoft's official ["not supported"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) statement. Make sure you are happy to enjoy pain to get it working.

Comment: Yes, the group I am writing this for feels very strongly about getting this to work, so I will have to deal with the pain :P

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue as what you have described, the excel instance hangs and macro doesn't run.
I finally found it was a permission issue. after configuring DCOM, it works!

> 1. Start -> dcomcnfg.exe (you might be prompted for administrator credentials) -> Console Root -> Component Services -> My Computer -> DCOM Config
> 2. Click “Microsoft Excel Application”. Right Click -> Properties.
> 3. Choose Identity tab. Select Security tab.
>    make sure the user account that your service log on as has been added into each customize on this page. (**warning**: even if the admin group has been added and the user account is admin group member, you still need to add the user specially, maybe because of the control of windows UAC ).
> 4. Choose Identity tab. Select Identity tab.
>    select "launching user". <- note must be this, if you select "interactive user" and no one has logged on that server machine, macro won't run.